# How to make this random generator work more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this little generator that chooses a random item from an array and displays it as text in a div. But for some reason it only functions one time, I just want to know how to make it keep replacing the text whenever you click it.

```
var items = Array(523,3452,334,31,5346);
var random = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)]

$('#btn').click(function(){
  $('#box').text(random);
})
```

Yes, I suck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put `var random` **inside** the click function :)

```js
var items = [523, 3452, 334, 31, 5346];

$('#btn').click(function() {
  var random = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
  $('#box').text(random);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">PICK RANDOM</button>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: This is working great, thank you! Is there also a way to make it display 3 different randomly selected objects from the same array each time the button is clicked too?

Comment: @Joel yes, one idea is to first shuffle your array (Google it) and than simply pick the first three keys like `items = shuffle(items); $('#box').text(items[0]+' '+items[1]+' '+items[2]);`

Comment: OK great, I'm going to look it up now!